# Normalizing variables '0_1' looks better than z-scores in R

Tags: r, neural-networks, normalization

Here is a toy-example, where '0_1' looks better than 'norm'. Using 'norm'(z-scores) has a huge training error and almost constant prediction.

```
library(RSNNS)
x <- runif(1020, 1, 5000)
y <- sqrt(x)
#0_1 type
x.01 <- normalizeData(x, type='0_1')
y.01 <- normalizeData(y, type='0_1')
model.01 <- mlp(x.01[1:1000], y.01[1:1000], size = 1)
py.01 <- predict(model.01, matrix(x.01[1001:1020], ncol=1))
py.01 <- denormalizeData(py.01, getNormParameters(y.01))
#norm type
x.n <- normalizeData(x, type='norm')
y.n <- normalizeData(y, type='norm')
model.n <- mlp(x.n[1:1000], y.n[1:1000], size = 1)
py.n <- predict(model.n, matrix(x.n[1001:1020], ncol=1))
py.n <- denormalizeData(py.n, getNormParameters(y.n))
#print
res <- cbind(y[1001:1020], py.01, py.n)
colnames(res) <- c('target', '0_1', 'norm')
print(res)
    target      0_1     norm
 [1,]  7.847747 18.42934 47.98046
 [2,] 20.128710 21.63094 47.98193
 [3,] 51.883655 54.31361 50.05302
 [4,] 39.988633 38.61841 48.02621
 [5,] 37.763832 35.78068 48.00804
 [6,] 36.182139 33.88958 48.00035
 [7,] 49.259397 51.15189 48.77056
 [8,]  9.989678 18.74624 47.98058
 [9,] 37.053090 34.91668 48.00420
[10,] 67.759140 65.00623 64.26272
[11,] 40.238815 38.94849 48.02908
[12,] 55.269081 57.80950 54.15643
[13,] 68.659288 65.26538 64.33199
[14,] 67.240699 64.84575 64.21361
[15,] 32.216679 29.69490 47.99008
[16,] 37.735459 35.74576 48.00787
[17,] 43.830574 43.84002 48.10858
[18,]  8.959444 18.58314 47.98052
[19,] 22.715183 22.83997 47.98266
[20,] 58.814483 60.69753 59.91301
```

Why doesn't using z-scores work here?

I'm use [RSNNS package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/index.html)

Comment: which is the part where you are computing z-scores?

Comment: @Glen_b I clarified my question. It should be clear now. Thanks for help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rsnns` so it would help if you would explain why _any_ normalization is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from `mlp` is always positive, so those values that should be negative are predicted to be very close to zero.  Thus after back-transformation they are all close to the mean.